# How to count the most recent consecutive occurrences of a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am given a list of cities that will record high pollution levels tomorrow. I have a dictionary with the last few days and which cities recorded very high pollution levels on those days.

```
tomorrow = ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'Karachi', 'Noida']

high_pollution = {0: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'Tokyo'], 1: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'New York'], 2: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'New York', 'Tokyo', 'LA'], 3: ['Noida', 'Lahore', 'Tokyo', 'Sakhir'], 4: ['Delhi', 'Chengdu', 'Karachi'], 5: ['Delhi', 'Lahore' 'Chengdu', 'Sakhir', 'Tokyo']}
```

They key is the day (i.e. 0 is today, 1 means yesterday, 5 means 5 days ago). The data updates each day so tomorrow there will be 8 keys and after a year there will be 372 keys, with each of the current keys moving down 1 number i.e. what is today the 0 key value will tomorrow be the 1 key value and the "tomorrow" list currently will then be mapped to the key 0.

I need to count the number of consecutive days that a city that will appear in tomorrow list (data given to me) has appeared in the dict in the past. Ex. for Delhi, it has appeared in each of the last 5 days. I don't care that it also appeared 7 days ago if it didn't appear on the 6th day as well, I only care about the most recent consecutive appearances. I need to know this number for each of the cities in the current day dict, i.e. for Delhi, Lahore, Beijing, Karachi and Noida.

By eyeballing it, I know these numbers will be 5, 5, 3, 1, 1. I need a list of these numbers:

```
days = [5, 5, 3, 1, 1]
```

I tried this code:

```
days = [0] * len(tomorrow)

for num in range(len(tomorrow):
    for i in range(len(high_pollution)-1):
        if tomorrow[num] in high_pollution[i] and high_pollution[i+1]:
            days[num] = days[num] + 1
        if not tomorrow[num] in high_pollution[i] and high_pollution[i+1]:
            break
```

But this gives me days = [2, 3, 1, 0, 0] which is completely off.

Comment: Replace `if tomorrow[num] in high_pollution[i] and high_pollution[i+1]` by `if tomorrow[num] in high_pollution[i] and tomorrow[num] in high_pollution[i+1]`. The second `if` can be replaced by an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive solution:

Code:

```
tomorrow = ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'Karachi', 'Noida']

high_pollution = {0: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'Tokyo'], 1: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'Beijing', 'New York'], 2: ['Delhi', 'Lahore', 'New York', 'Tokyo', 'LA'], 3: ['Noida', 'Lahore', 'Tokyo', 'Sakhir'], 4: ['Delhi', 'Chengdu', 'Karachi'], 5: ['Delhi', 'Lahore' 'Chengdu', 'Sakhir', 'Tokyo']}

days = [0] * len(tomorrow)

def recent_consecutive_days(city, list_, n):
    
    if city not in list_:
        return 1
    
    return 1 + recent_consecutive_days(city, high_pollution[n + 1], n+1)
    
    
days = list(map(lambda x: recent_consecutive_days(x, high_pollution[0], 0), tomorrow))
print(days)
```

Note that the value for "Delhi" should actually be 4, not 5.

Output:

```
[4, 5, 3, 1, 1]
```

Comment: The value for Lahore should be 4, and it should be 2 for Beijing, isn't it?

Comment: @Gugu72 that is what I thought at first, but I believe they are including the "tomorrow" list in their calculation.

Comment: Hence the `return 1` and not `return 0`

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, when I run this, on line 12 i get KeyError: 6. How can that be avoided?